# Computing the porosity of a core sample from a set of digital images

Tags: geophysics, porous-media

Are there any references of books and/or papers about methods to compute the porosity of a given core sample (from an oil and gas reservoir) if this core is given as a set of digital images (for example, the images can be generated by means of computer tomography). Is there any source of information comparing methods and their advantges/disadvantages ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty sure that a lot of work must have already been done in that area. If you have images from tomography, have you looked at the free image processing package Fiji and its included library of plug-in routines?

Comment: https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1029/JZ066i010p03279